# How to solve "No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid" when I want terminate the app?

Tags: swift, cocoa

When I want terminate my app I am getting this massage from Xcode:

> No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid

I am using this code, it make the massage happen:

```
NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
```

Comment: Do you just want to Terminate the app whenever you get this?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

You probably don't need to do anything, it's just [log noise](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461).

**Long Answer:**

I don't know what it means or how to make it go away. But there's a general advice advice from Apple Developer Technical Support that I would paraphrase as this:

*When you see a debug message, ask yourself:*

- *is the message related to any failure or misbehavior in your app?*
- *does the message have any relation to your APIs or code?*

*If both answers are NO, it's just [log noise](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461) and you can simply ignore them.*

Personally, I see
`[client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid` in debugger of one of my apps since I upgraded to Ventura, whenever I quit this app from UI or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `NSXPCListener`.

Consult these docs to learn more:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistener

Here's a quick example using Objective-C:

```objectivec
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface Delegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@end
@implementation Delegate
@end
int main()
{
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setDelegate: [[Delegate alloc] init]];

    NSXPCListener *listener =
            [NSXPCListener serviceListener];

    [NSApp run];
}
```